# "lock to launcher" caused problem

Tags: graphics, window, opengl, matlab

I am using ubuntu 16.06

since I tried "lock to launcher" for MATLAB, the screen of MATLAB has become  see through/transparent,

applying unlock did not work

thank you for your help

Comment: This change in screen appearance is not related to locking the launcher. Have you tried if the issue persists after a reboot? What version of matlab is involved here?

Comment: thank you for your reply, the version is  '(R2019a) Update 4',  the screen renders normally once after every 7 to 10 unsuccessful launches,  I cannot reboot the machine at this stage but I will give that a try, cheers